# C++ template argument deduction process

Tags: c++

Can anyone help tell me why the argument deduction is not working how I would anticipate? Please see my code comments for my line of thinking?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void deduce1(T args, string arg){
cout << "template<class T> void deduce1(T args) " << " argument passed in was: " << arg << " deduced as: " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
cout <<  "Is const: " << boolalpha << is_const<T>::value << endl;
cout <<  "Is reference: " << boolalpha << is_reference<T>::value << endl;
cout <<  "Is pointer: " << boolalpha << is_pointer<T>::value << endl;
}

template<class T>
void deduce2(T& args,string arg){
cout << "template<class T> void deduce2(T args) " << " argument passed in was: " << arg << " deduced as: " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
cout <<  "Is const: " << boolalpha << is_const<T>::value << endl;
cout <<  "Is reference: " << boolalpha << is_reference<T>::value << endl;
cout <<  "Is pointer: " << boolalpha << is_pointer<T>::value << endl;
}

template<class T>
void deduce3(T&& args,string arg){
cout << "template<class T> void deduce3(T args) " << " argument passed in was: " << arg << " deduced as: " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
cout <<  "Is const: " << boolalpha << is_const<T>::value << endl;
cout <<  "Is reference: " << boolalpha << is_reference<T>::value << endl;
cout <<  "Is rvalue reference: " << boolalpha << is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << endl;
cout <<  "Is pointer: " << boolalpha << is_pointer<T>::value << endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int a = 1;
const int b = 5;
int c[] = {12};
int const d[] = {12};
int& e = a;

deduce1(a,"int a = 1");
deduce1(b,"const int b = 5");
deduce1(c,"int c[] = {12}");
deduce1(d,"int const d[] = {12}"); // would have thought is_const<T> would return true any comments?
deduce1(e,"int& e = a");
deduce1(5,"5");

deduce2(a,"int a = 1");
deduce2(b,"const int b = 5"); //would have though type would be deduced as int const comments?
deduce2(c,"int c[] = {12}"); // why is this not returning true as a reference?
deduce2(d,"int const d[] = {12}"); // would have thought is_const<T> would return true any comments
deduce2(e,"int& e = a");

deduce3(a,"int a = 1");
deduce3(b,"const int b = 5");
deduce3(c,"int c[] = {12}"); // why is this not returning true as a reference?
deduce3(d,"int const d[] = {12}"); // would have thought is_const<T> would return true any comments
deduce3(e,"int& e = a");
deduce3(string("Hello"),"string(\"Hello\")"); // why not rvalue reference


return 0;
}
```

Comment: References cannot be const. You need to `remove_reference ` before checking.

Comment: Can you paste an example of what you mean?

Comment: Perhaps this may help concerning `const`: [link](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/04/appearing-and-disappearing-consts-in-c/)

Comment: Note that `d` is not `const`, but the elements of the array are. The standard states in §3.9.3 2: Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tackle each of your comments in turn.

1. `deduce1` with `d`:

   ```
   template <class T> void deduce1(T args, string arg);
   int const d[] = {12};
   deduce1(d, "int const d[] = {12}"); // would have thought is_const<T> would return true
   ```

   The first important thing is that you can't pass arrays as arguments by value in C++. Expressions denoting an array will decay almost immediately to a pointer to its first element. So the type deduced for `T` here will be `int const *`.

   So still, why won't this work? The problem is that the *pointer* is not `const`. The `int`s that the pointer is pointing to are `const`. If you want to report the `const`ness of the type being pointed to, you'll need to use `remove_pointer` before checking the `const`ness. So you would change your `const` checking to:

   ```
   cout <<  "Is const: " << boolalpha << is_const<typename remove_pointer<T>::type>::value << endl;
   ```

   However, the result it was giving before was the correct answer. The pointer was indeed not `const`. In fact, even if the pointer were `const`, top-level `consts` are stripped off before type deduction is done so `T` would not be `const` anyway. The reason for this is that, if you're passing by value, you really don't care about the `const`ness of the argument since you're copying it anyway.
2. `deduce2` with `b`:

   ```
   template <class T> void deduce2(T& args,string arg);
   const int b = 5;
   deduce2(b,"const int b = 5"); //would have though type would be deduced as int const
   ```

   Not sure what's happening for you here, but my output is:

   ```
   deduced as: i
   Is const: true
   Is reference: false
   Is pointer: false
   ```

   Exactly as expected.
3. `deduce2` with `c`:

   ```
   int c[] = {12};
   deduce2(c,"int c[] = {12}"); // why is this not returning true as a reference?
   ```

   It's saying that it's not a reference for the same reason all of the `deduce2` calls say that (and you have this problem throughout `deduce3` too). In your function, you're checking the type of `T` but the type of `args` is `T&`. You're only checking the part before the `&`. So here, the type of `args` is `int (&)[1] c` but you're just checking if `int [1]` is a reference. Fix it by using `decltype(args)` instead of `T` in your checks.
4. `deduce2` with `d`:

   ```
   int const d[] = {12};
   deduce2(d,"int const d[] = {12}"); // would have thought is_const<T> would return true
   ```

   Same problem as `deduce1` with `d` (item 1).
5. `deduce3` with `c`:

   ```
   template <class T> void deduce3(T&& args,string arg);
   int c[] = {12};
   deduce3(c,"int c[] = {12}"); // why is this not returning true as a reference?
   ```

   Same problem as `deduce2` with `c` (item 3).
6. `deduce3` with `d`:

   ```
   int const d[] = {12};
   deduce3(d,"int const d[] = {12}"); // would have thought is_const<T> would return true
   ```

   Same problem as `deduce1` with `d` (item 1).
7. `deduce3` with `string("Hello")`:

   ```
   deduce3(string("Hello"),"string(\"Hello\")"); // why not rvalue reference
   ```

   I'm going to assume you know something about "universal references". Scott Meyers has a great [article](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) and [talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) on the subject.

   In this case, because `string("Hello")` is an rvalue expression, the type `T` is deduced as `string` (by the rules of deduced rvalue reference types of the form `T&&`). The type of `args` is now `string &&`. So if you check if `decltype(args)` is an rvalue, it'll say true. But `T` itself is not.

If you fix your code so that all type traits on `T` are now on `decltype(args)`, you'll get a new problem. When args is of reference type, certain types that you expect to be `const` won't be. That's because there's no such thing as a `const` reference. Similar to using `remove_pointer` in item 1, you'll need to use `remove_reference` to get at the underlying type and check if that is `const`.

Comment: In your point 3. This is not correct. There is no array to pointer conversion here. The type `T` is deduced to be `int [1]`, i.e. _array of 1 int_. This is one place, where it is important to distinguish between pointers and arrays.

Comment: @MWid Ah good point, I was thinking of it as `T` in `deduce1`, not as `T&`. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Makes total sense now !